Css transform zoom in and out scrolling issue
I have 3 divs with the transform being on the 2nd div which has a div inside of that. I have added zoom in and zoom out buttons but when I zoom in I can't scroll all the way to the left and top but don't have issues when scrolling to the right and bottom. I also want some padding so the parent div is shown a little when zoomed in. I am trying to replicate a pdf viewer.
Initial view before zoom in  with the transform scale on the red div
Zoomed in and scrolled to bottom right can always see the red div
Zoomed in and scrolled all the way to top left I cannot see the red div which is the issue
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Home() {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);

  const handleZoomIn = () => {
    setScale((prevScale) => prevScale + 0.1);
  };

  const handleZoomOut = () => {
    setScale((prevScale) => prevScale - 0.1);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100vw",
        height: "calc(100vh - 80px)",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
               padding: "10px"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={handleZoomIn}>Zoom In</button>
      <button onClick={handleZoomOut}>Zoom Out</button>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "40%",
          height: "100%",
          background: "yellow",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          overflow:"scroll",
   
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: "80%",
            background: "red",
            height: "80%",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            transform: `scale(${scale})`,
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{ width: "95%", background: "blue", height: "95%" }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;

Just not sure on what to do to solve this

I am not sure if I follow and understood the problem correctly, but here goes my sandbox
I added some content to the zoomed in box so that zoom in effect is more visible. What you need to do is to ensure that the container <div style={{ width: "80%", height: "80%", overflow: "auto" }}> has overflow: auto to enable scrolling.
I used ref to center the zoomed in div based on the scale. I don't know if this was requirement, but it looked more natural to me.
What I would also advise is to remove magic numbers like width: "95%" Here is a great article to read about smelly css and how to avoid magic numbers as such.
